# mysqli_num_rows error when uploaded to webserver

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece of code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM delegations where EMail='". $_REQUEST["user"] ."' AND Password = '". Encrypt($_REQUEST["pass"]) ."' ";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

        $_SESSION["login"] = $row["ID"];
        echo "Welcome <b>" . $row["FirstName"] . "</b>! You have logged in succesfully! <a href=\"index.php\">Click here</a> to continue!";

    }
```

Which runs fine when I run it on my localhost xampp. However, when I upload it to my web-server I get the following error code:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
boolean given in *path*/login.php on line 28
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `mysqli` itself does not prevent sql injection. Start using prepared statements.

Comment: Also I have high hopes function `Encrypt` is intended to hash passwords not to encrypt them.

Comment: Suggestion for now and forever - if you have a boolean function, do check what result you get back. You didn't check whether query succeeds. I really don't know why people don't check functions for their return values, it'd probably reduce 50% of questions on SO and save me downvotes (in case you're wondering why you got a downvote here - it's because you didn't google nor read php documentation).

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error( $con ));
```

I think $results should be false; Using `mysqli_error` you can track this.

otherwise check

```
var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `mysqli_query` is failing, please add a error handler to display the error.

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Ok, turns out the privileges of the MySQL user hadn't been setup properly. Thanks!